# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Task'

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been getting the following error on my Flutter Application:

> The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Task'.

this is my **homepage.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_to_do/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_to_do/screens/taskpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_to_do/widgets.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  DatabaseHelper _dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          color: const Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 32.0,
                      bottom: 32.0,
                    ),
                    child: const Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      initialData: [],
                      future: _dbHelper.getTasks(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        return ScrollConfiguration(
                          behavior: NoGlowBehaviour(),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Taskpage(
                                        task: snapshot.data[index],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ).then(
                                    (value) {
                                      setState(() {});
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                child: TaskCardWidget(
                                  title: snapshot.data[index].title,
                                  desc: snapshot.data[index].description,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Taskpage(
                                task: null,
                              )),
                    ).then((value) {
                      setState(() {});
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: const LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Color(0xFF7349FE), Color(0xFF643FDB)],
                          begin: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
                          end: Alignment(0.0, 1.0)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    child: const Image(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        "assets/images/add_icon.png",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error happens at:

> task: null
> (line 85)

I am a beginner at flutter and been trying to solve this issue for a while now. What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Are you following a specific tutorial ? I'm asking because it might be old a bit and not using "null safety" but your newly created project runs with null safety. make sure to check the versions in pubscpec.yaml

Comment: Yes! I am following an older tutorial! I'll check pubscpec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You are triyng to navigate to another screen, passing an argument as `null` and then you use `setState`. Basically setState will rebuild everytinh under your build method. Try to review this part of your code.

```
Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Taskpage(
                                task: null,
                              )),
                    ).then((value) {
                      setState(() {});
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a nullable exception. Try doing this: task: `snapshot.data[index]!`

Otherwise you should allow the task attribute to be nullable by declaring it with a **?** before the variable type instead. For more info on nullables in dart visit [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)